# D2D1 failed initializing Imaging factory

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, direct2d, wic

I am new to d2d1, and tried to use LoadImageFromFile function from msdn to load mitmap, it need as one of it arguments pointer to IWICImagingFactory, because i need to pass it into the function, it must be initialized ant can`t be NULL, how to initialize it with non NULL value, or how to pass it into the function?
Visual studio 2019.
Thanks for help/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `CoCreateInstance` with `CLSID_WICImagingFactory` argument. See this question, for example: [CoCreateInstance of IWICImagingFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799179/cocreateinstance-of-iwicimagingfactory)

Or this intro: [Introduction to WIC: How to use WIC to load an image, and draw it with GDI?](http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2011/10/17/introduction-to-wic-how-to-use-wic-to-load-an-image-and-draw-it-with-gdi/)

Or, [this sample](https://github.com/krish3402/dotnet/blob/d42a2ea76a6d50c6790bbcf88a60de73cce069a9/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/Direct2D/SaveAsImageFileSample/SaveAsImageFileSample.cpp#L96):

```
    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWICImagingFactory,
        reinterpret_cast<void **>(&pWICFactory)
        );
```

Or this [SimpleDirect2DApplication](https://github.com/krish3402/dotnet/tree/d42a2ea76a6d50c6790bbcf88a60de73cce069a9/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/Direct2D/SimpleDirect2DApplication) sample which features Driect2D and WIC capabilities to load from file.